# Fazendo Calculo do IMC não estou conseguindo só da o resultado 80

Tags: c, c++, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{      
    float peso,altura,imc;
    imc=0;
    printf("digite seu peso ?");
    scanf("%f",&peso);
    printf("digite sua altura? ");
    scanf("%f",&altura);
    imc= (peso/pow(altura,2 )); //usando a função pow
    printf(" IMC igual a  %10.2f ",imc);

    return 0;
}
```

e sem usar a função `pow`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{      float peso,altura,imc;
   imc=0;
    printf("digite seu peso ?");
    scanf("%f",&peso);
    printf("digite sua altura? ");
    scanf("%f",&altura);   // usando a função pow
    imc= (peso/altura*altura) ; // sem a função pow
    printf(" IMC igual a  %10.2f ",imc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Gabriel**, você pode [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/329878/edit) a pergunta e descrever o problema, caso necessite de ajuda sobre como utilizar a ferramenta, acesse a [help].

Answer (score 7):

No primeiro teste não foi possivel reproduzir seu problema:

> https://ideone.com/m4IVad

No segundo é erro básico de matemática.

Primeiro você divide peso pela altura, depos você multiplica pela altura:

```
     peso/altura*altura
// 1 ----^
// 2 -----------^
```

O resultado, adivinhe? Vai ser a altura<sup>1</sup>...

Veja a diferença com os parênteses no lugar apropriado:

```
imc = peso/(altura*altura);
```

> https://ideone.com/LTEK5K

<sub><sup>1. exceto diferenças de arredondamento que não vem ao caso neste exercício.</sup></sub>.